# Why does Folger give Muir a confused look in this scene at the end of Spy Game?

Tags: spy-game

It's the last 5 minutes of the [movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrC470sHOBY). See clip @approx 0:08.

> Someone in the room:  "Are we done here?"
>
> Harker: "Non-disclosure agreement."
>
> Muir quickly signs the NDA.
>
> Folger: "Aren't you gonna read it?"
>
> Muir: "Read it a thousand times."
>
> --> Folger makes eye contact with Muir and looks confused.
>
> Harker: "Aiken... will you escort Mr. Muir from the building?"

Why does Folger look at him that way?  It's as if Folger was thinking that someone like Muir would *always* read the fine print.  That doesn't make any sense to me because Muir really would have seen thousands of these after that long in the CIA and I'm sure they are all mostly boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no research for this, but maybe Folger is considering that Muir has not been disclosing things to *them* - having signed a thousand NDAs, he is a man who keeps secrets. Moments later they discover his deception.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but this seems like something that Folger would have already thought about.  Why would Muir's signing the NDA prompt Folger to realize that Muir would be unlikely to compromise on his previous commitments?  I think it is Muir's statement, "Read it a thousand times." that really seems to stun Folger. Perhaps it's the converse of what you're saying: Muir has been in the CIA so long that he actually hasn't signed any NDAs at all!

Comment: You have to wonder why the scene is there at all. It's the signing of a document - not really exciting to watch. But it is building tension - will Muir make it out of the building before they realize what he has done? Somehow this signing, and that comment, are moving Muir closer to getting caught out. In the exchange of looks between the two men, you can see that something has been communicated that is new. It is a puzzle! Will keep looking for clues...

Comment: That's why I like that scene so much.  Folger and Muir go way back and so I've always imagined that at that moment, Folger realized that his old friend was lying about something, but couldn't quite see what yet.  But how did he know??

Answer (score 1):

There may be something to Folger's and Muir's history -- maybe Muir's *always* read the NDA's and this is a departure.

But regardless of that, here's my theory:  Non-disclosure agreements often bind both parties.  Muir can't talk without violating the agreement, but neither can the CIA. And if they do break the agreement, all bets are off.  So if that's the case, Muir may realize that he's actually protecting himself and his fake op by signing the agreement.